# How to add close icon in mobile menu?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, css

I want to **change Bar Icons** to **Close Icon** on hamburger menu, when it's expanded

Like in below images , **menu is expanded and still there are menu bars on right top.** I want to change that into close icon.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can do it via changing css of menu.

Comment: can't find any css , kindly help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the **menu icon from bar to close icon** when expanded follow the steps below:

Create `_extend.less` at below location with same directory structure if not exists:

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Now add below css for changing bar icons to close icon:

```
.nav-open .nav-toggle::before {
    content: '\e616';
}
```

After that run following commands if you are in developer mode while keeping cache disabled:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

In production mode , also run below command with above commands to take effect.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

**Note: Tested on LUMA theme**

I hope this will help you out as **I tested it on custom theme based on LUMA theme**